# Karate Getting Reference Error not defined

Tags: reference, karate

One feature file is calling another feature file and passing a value as parameter. I have tried the same approach for another project and it worked. When i try now I'm getting the below error message

*com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: get-id.feature:10 - javascript evaluation failed: PID, ReferenceError: "PID" is not defined in  at line number 1
at ✽.Given param p_id = PID (get-id.feature:10)*

Calling feature:

```
Background:
  And def response = call read('classpath:docGen/get-id.feature') {PID: '123456'}
  And print response
  And def ID = response.response['id-abc']

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

get-id.feature
Feature: Authorization using id-abc
 Background:     
    * url idURL
   
Scenario: Get the id-abc from member number 
  
Given param p_id = PID
When method GET
Then status 201
```

Comment: sorry, the only way we can solve these kinds of vague questions, is if you can follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue